# Three.js scene not displaying after replacing renderer

Tags: javascript, three.js

Update: re-wrote the question to make it more general.
(Original [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28158936/1) for reference)

I am rendering a scene in a Three.js WebGLRenderer. Then I need to replace the renderer with a new WebGLRenderer (replacing the canvas with a new canvas) and render the same scene again in the new renderer.

The setup looks roughly like this:

```
cancelAnimationFrame(this.requestID_);
// all other Three.js objects stay same (and I let Three.js create a new canvas)
this.createNewRenderer();
this.animate();
```

However, the new renderer will just render an empty background, and not the scenes meshes.
If I replace the scene meshes with newly calculated meshes, rendering is fine again.

Therefore I assume it has something to do with the meshes.

So, to avoid recalculating the mesh, I've tried setting all geometry.xxxNeedUpdate and material.needUpdate flags as per [this three.js doc](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates) before (and after) creating the new renderer, but this hasn't worked either.

What can I do to "force refresh" the meshes to display again in a new WebGLRenderer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently solving this by refreshing every mesh in the scene as follows:

```
mesh.geometry = mesh.geometry.clone();
mesh.material = mesh.material.clone();
newMesh = mesh.clone();
```